# This one might be a toughie

Tags: riddle, word, visual

The images below can be connected by a single word.

1. [image: browser icon]
2. [image: ned flanders]
3. [image: roof rat and norway rat]
4. [image: the boyz]
5. [image: fallout vault boy]
6. [image: character concept art for Ubisoft's For Honor]
7. [image: red text]
8. [image: lego character]
9. [image: lego character]

What is the word and what are the connections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the word is:

> **HOOD**.

The connections are:

1. > Hoodie – Hood + IE, Internet Explorer, that is
2. > Neighbourhood – Flanders is the Simpsons' neighbour.
3. > Hood Rats
4. > Boyz n the Hood
5. > Hoodwink – `;)`
6. > Knighthood
7. > Little Red Riding Hood
8. > Hood ornament – on a car's radiator ✽
9. > Robin Hood – the figure is of Batman's sidekick Robin

As for the title:

> A hood (a gangster or rough person) might be a toughie.

✽ Thanks to the many helpful commenters who pointed me into the right direction on the connection to the hanging Harry Potter Christmas-tree decoration (8).

Comment: Okay, I'll dig some more. Oh, I now see it's Boyz in the (da?) hood!

Comment: Maybe the 4th connection is the movie title "Boyz n the Hood"

Comment: @SherlockHolmes: Thanks. I think I've got them now, although I'm not too sure about the HP one. Or is it that the Hogwarts uniforms have hoods?

Comment: @MOehm for 8 if it's unrelated to Harry Potter, it's an ornament kind of on a Christmas tree and it's a Lego. If that helps at all :)

Comment: Ornament has to be it - hood ornament, like on the front of a car.

Comment: Could also be child Harry - childhood

Comment: Aha, didn't know that either the Christmas tree decorations or the figurines on a bonnet were called ornaments. To me, ornament suggests painted or bas-relief garlands, not free-hanging or -standing things.

Comment: Pretty much anything that gets hung on a tree gets referred to as an ornament in my home.. differences of culture I guess

Comment: @n_palum: Yeah, that was no criticism, just a half-arsed attempt to defend why I couldn't get the connection, which is rather obvious in hindsight. (English and German share a lot of words that seem to have the same meaning, but have subtle differences.)

Comment: Nice job, have a ✔